# Combine two mysql rows into one

Tags: mysql

I have these following two rows in mysql database table

```
  Chart_date      chart_field            chart_counts
  20131115  user_jrFeed_item_count      {"1":2}
  20131115  user_jrForum_item_count     {"1":1}
```

How can I create another row that achieves the result below

```
Chart_date    chart_field                                 chart_counts
  20131115  user_jrFeed_item_count,user_jrForum_item_count  {"1":2},{"1":1}
```

OR

```
  Chart_date    chart_field   chart_counts
  20131115  new description   {"1":2},{"1":1}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I want to create 1 single data-field to extract/read data from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Chart_date,GROUP_CONCAT(chart_field )as chart_field,
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(chart_counts),'2},{','2,')as chart_counts 
FROM table WHERE Chart_date='20131115' GROUP BY Chart_date
```

Comment: I want to get data from those two rows only.The actual table has 4O different data-fields/rows.How can I achieve this?   The answer you gave is in the right direction

Comment: WHERE Chart_field='user_jrFeed_item_count,user_jrForum_item_count'.Is this possible?

Comment: You could add WHERE Chart_field LIKE 'user_jrF%' But it depends on those other fields.

Comment: Or WHERE Chart_field IN('user_jrFeed_item_count','user_jrForum_item_count')

Comment: It's working.Just one more question-Can I get {"1":2,"1":1} instead of {"1":2},{"1":1}